# Login with google account fire base

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have developed an app that should allow users to login with their Google account using Firebase authentication. However, after I run the app and try to log in, the account is taken and I see that it is present in the Firebase authentication, but the app does not navigate to the home page. What is wrong with my code?
Background:

I have followed the steps provided in the Firebase documentation for integrating Google sign-in with Firebase authentication. I have also tried to troubleshoot the issue by checking for syntax errors and debugging the code, but it still does not work.

Please provide the code or relevant portions of the code that you have written for the authentication process to better understand the issue and provide a solution.

Comment: `not navigate to the home page.` can you help us what you've done by providing minimal snippet

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"